# Internet Explorer 11 will not show videos after running CCleaner Registry Cleaner

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I recently used CCleaner’s Registry scan and deleted all the files that showed up without making backup. After that, my IE11 got a real problem, Now I couldn’t see the YouTube videos I previously watched. Any video I’ve watched, the next time I try to watch the same video it won’t able to load. Why is it?

I am not certain about the files I’ve deleted, but I think I may have deleted one or more registry files of IE.

I am using Win 7 SP-1 64bit OS

Comment: [See this page](https://askleo.com/how-do-i-reinstall-internet-explorer/)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like IE's link to the Flash Player is broken. Try reinstalling the Flash Player, found here:

https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/

Be sure to uncheck the McAfee junkware offer ;-)

Comment: Ok. I misunderstood your post then. In that case, I'd recommend doing as Moab suggested above, and doing a reinstall of IE11. it's a fairly simple process, and it won't destroy your bookmarks  or anything.

Comment: I have no addon enabled. There is something called Shockwave Flash object which is in `disabled`. A video I watch first time won’t load for the second time but there is no problem with new videos. I`ve reinstalled IE but still persisting.

Comment: By the way there is a IE key in both HKCU>SOFTWARE>MICROSOFT>INTERNET EXPLORE and HKLM [the same path as HKCU]. I am thinking to delete these folders and then reninstall IE. Share me your take on this.

Comment: when you reinstalled IE before, did you *uninstall* the previous one first? You do that in Programs & Features, on the left hand side there is a link to 'Turn Windows Features On & Off'.  [full instructions here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/318378) - following these instructions should full repair IE and you should not need to do manual registry edits.

Comment: Yes I did the way you mentioned.

Comment: So, to understand the problem, when you go to Youtube and watch a video that you had watched in the past, it will no longer play? is that correct? and videos that are new to you, *will* play? If this is the case, I'd recommend attempting to relocate IE's cache location, [per these instructions](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/restore-temporary-internet-files-folder-ie-11)

Comment: Yes, that’s the case thus I am reviewing your instructions. By the way IE11 is important to me  it buffers youtube videos faster than any other browser. Living in a country which provides  4 GB data package for US$ 20. Guess what!

Comment: My **Temporary Internet Files**  folder is located in `C:\users\user\appdata\local\microsoft\windows\Internet temporary files\`   .   There is no folder called `INetCache`.  Anyway I have relocated its current location to one of my personal folder.